# How to install Laravel Valet on Mac Mojave?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-valet

I'm trying to install Laravel Valet on my system using Homebrew. I'm on the step where I'm installing Composer. I'm trying to install it globally.
After installing it says:
`Composer (version 2.0.12) successfully installed to: /Users/ryan/composer.phar`
But when I try to check the version using `composer -v`, it says:
`Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar`.
Why is it looking there? Also, this is what I have in my PATH's file:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

I think it's a PATH issue, but I'm not sure.
Thank you.

Comment: Please share more details. If you assume that this is a path problem, why not resolve it? Also, how is this related to [tag:laravel-valet]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the composer.phar and composer.json files to this location:
`/usr/local/bin/`. That solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did paste this code at Terminal, at my local dir:

`composer && bash ~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet install || bash ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/valet install`